# Distributed issue tracker for git with usable Eclipse Mylyn support?

Tags: eclipse, git, distributed, issue-tracking, mylyn

I'm using **git** for version control but I'm currently lacking a good **issue/bug/ticket tracker** with Eclipse Mylyn integration.

The features I'm looking for:

- **Open source** implementation (so that I can add the features I need in the future. GPL, LGPL, MIT or BSD license preferred).
- **Distributed** (the issues *must* be stored in git the repository, I'm open for suggestions for trackers that store issues in the same or separate branch to the code).
- Must have **Eclipse Mylyn** support (so that I can open and close issues through mylyn interface, I think a sensible implementation could provide a localhost HTTP server in a specific port and mylyn would use "web template" connector to speak with the issue tracker). Preferably the Mylyn would automatically see issues opening and closing as I switch branches but I'm okay with this being less smart.
- Able to **track issues between branches**, example:

  - I have branches X and Y with a common parent commit Z.
  - the commit Z has an open issue Z1.
  - the branch Y has a fix (commit Y4) and closes the issue in Y.
  - the branch Y has a new issue (commit Y2)
  - the branch Y is merged in X.
  - the issue tracker automatically knows that the issue Z1 is fixed in X but there's now a new issue from commit Y2.
- Able to deal with the case where multiple repositories open, modify and close same or different issues (the distributed part, I'm just making this explicit).
- Must be runnable on 64 bit and 32 bit linux (ubuntu 10.04 for now)
- Preferably implemented in bash, c/c++, python or perl (possibly java or ruby, too).

Secondary features (would be nice but I can live without):

- Small enough to be included in the project's source code: preferrably a single file with an executable bit set (e.g. a single bash or python script with full implementation)
- Some kind of web user interface so that people without Eclipse Mylyn can at least add new issues and add comments to existing ones (no need to be able to set priorities or even close issues)

Can you suggest **anything**?

**Update:** As of 2012-09-13 no suitable tool has been found. Summary of the best matches this far:

- [Bugs Everywhere](http://bugseverywhere.org/) - no Mylyn support, the status has been "Adrian Wilkins would like to see a Mylyn connector for BE" in the "Plannet features" for the last two years. Otherwise the project keeps going.
- [git-issues](https://github.com/jwiegley/git-issues) - this project seems to be dead. Original author stopped making commits about two years ago and other authors have done less than ten commits in about last two years.
- [git-case](https://github.com/bartman/git-case) - this project seems to be dead. The original author stopped making commits three years ago.
- [stick](http://www.eharning.us/wiki/stick/) - this project seems to be dead. I couldn't even find public repository anymore.
- [TicGit](https://github.com/schacon/ticgit/wiki) this project seems to be dead. All repositories I could find have disclaimer that the project is no longer developed.
- [TigGit-NG](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit) - this projects seems to have died multiple times but this far, somebody has always adopted the project again. No Mylyn support here either. Requires pretty recent Ruby environment to run.
- [TicGit.net](https://github.com/henon/TicGit.net) - this project seems to be win32/.Net specific fork of TicGit written in C#. Does not match my needs.

Comment: Sure would be great if this existed...

Comment: I've played briefly with ticgit, though it doesn't have mylyn support.  I also don't think it can track changes between branches - it lives in its own branch (singular).

Comment: I'm pretty sure nowadays that the only correct way to implement this is to use a different branch from actual development. Rationale: (1) Ability to add bugs/issues/notes in historical commits and (2) git log is not spammed by issue tracker waste.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at [GitIssues](http://github.com/ktf/git-issues) which is well integrated with the git command line. But sadly, it doesn't support Mylyn. Nevertheless it should be easy to create a Mylyn connector since it can export to XML.

You can have a look at this [list](http://dist-bugs.kitenet.net/software/) of distributed bug tracking systems.

Comment: GitIssues looks interesting. Hopefully it gets Mylyn support soon. The git-case (http://dist-bugs.kitenet.net/people/bartman/git-case/) also seems to have a sane design. No mylyn support there either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Bugs Everywhere](http://bugseverywhere.org/)?  It says on the page that Mylyn support is still a requested feature, but I think it meets almost all of your other requirements.  (Just to be clear, I haven't actually tried out this myself, but it looks like a very sensible approach to me.)

Comment: Bugs Everywhere seems a bit too complex for my taste and still does not provide Mylyn support. This project seems to have a lot of supporters so perhaps there's a good possibility for Mylyn support in the future. In the end, GitIssues looks more promising to me.

Comment: Bugs Everywhere does have an HTML interface, so if this is important to you, you might be able to write a Generic Connector for Bugs Everywhere. 
See http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn for a discussion of how someone did it for Redmine