# Does Mylyn support using Subversion or Mercurial as a task repository?

Tags: version-control, mylyn

One of my teammates said that he had at one point used Mylyn backed by Subversion as a task repository.  I believe this was several versions of Mylyn ago, and I have not found any documentation about setting something like this up in any of my searching.  Is this still a supported configuration and if so can you please let me know where I can download the appropriate connector.

If this isn't supported any longer do you have any recommendations for a lightweight task repository that is both free and easy to install and configure?  Right now it's looking like Trac backed by Sqlite is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you what you want:
   http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/08/26/local-mylyn-tasks-distributed/

You might also want to check out this thread:
   [Distributed issue tracker for git with usable Eclipse Mylyn support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203272/distributed-issue-tracker-for-git-with-usable-eclipse-mylyn-support)